# AlertDialog not showing in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity with a button that starts an `AsyncTask`:

```
public void search(View view) {
    if (searchTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    searchTask = new SearchTask(this);
    searchTask.execute((Void)null);
}
```

And this is the task:

```
public class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final ProgressDialog dialog;

    public SearchTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            wait(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I'm not calling `get()` so I shouldn't be blocking the UI thread. The problem is that the progress dialog is not being shown.

Is this not the correct way to show a dialog within an `AsynTask`?

Comment: are you sure wait is getting called and there is no exception?

Comment: Check your LogCat for errors but besides that you shouldn't pass around the Activity around like you do (you are providing it to the AsyncTask). Instead, build the ProgressDialog object and pass it to the AsyncTask. Even better - use a DialogFragment.

Comment: Check that search method is really calls, also your searchTask will execute only once, because of "if (searchTask != null) { 
        return; 
    } "

Answer (score 0):

`wait()` causes `IllegelMonitorException`. to apply a delay in the task `Thread.sleep()` should be used.

Comment: You call dialog.show(); in onPreExecute, so your own answer is wrong

Comment: @Divers its not wrong. its not showing because the task is executing so fast because of the exception that the dialog does not have time to show

Comment: Than your question is wrong, because ProgressDialog appears

Comment: @Divers. It doesn't. He is catching exception and he is returning immediately.

Comment: @Divers if the dialog appeared why would he ask the question? Like I said the dialog does not have enough time to show because the task is executing so fast the dismiss is called before it showed

Answer (score 0):

try after removing **return;** from below code-

```
public void search(View view) {
    if (searchTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    searchTask = new SearchTask(this);
    searchTask.execute((Void)null);
}
```